# Error filling consuming a webservice, problems filling a array

Tags: vb.net

'Consuming webservice problem to fill a array

```
Dim apkvrg = New rdc.opvoerenMeldingAfkeuringAPK

apkvrg.VoertuigGebreken.VoertuigGebrek = "" 'error cannot conver 1-dimension
apkvrg.VoertuigGebreken.VoertuigGebrek(0).GebrekAantal = 1  'An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in apksoap.exe

                                                             'Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object     


        Private voertuigGebrekField() As VoertuigGebrekRaadplegen

        '''<remarks/>
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("VoertuigGebrek")>  _
        Public Property VoertuigGebrek() As VoertuigGebrekRaadplegen()
            Get
                Return Me.voertuigGebrekField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.voertuigGebrekField = value
            End Set
        End Property
       End Class

       Partial Public Class VoertuigGebrekRaadplegen

        Private gebrekIdentificatieField As String

        Private gebrekActieField As String

        Private gebrekAantalField As String

        Private gebrekToelichtingField As String

        Private gebrekOmschrijvingField As String

        '''<remarks/>
        Public Property GebrekIdentificatie() As String
            Get
                Return Me.gebrekIdentificatieField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.gebrekIdentificatieField = value
            End Set
        End Property
```

**xml webservice**

```
     <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rdc="http://nsp.rdc.nl/RDC">
     <soapenv:Header/>
     <soapenv:Body>
      <rdc:opvoerenMeldingAfkeuringAPK IndicatieLichtZwaar="Licht" Referentie="MB">
         <rdc:Kenteken>40MRDC</rdc:Kenteken>
         <rdc:Meldcode>0140</rdc:Meldcode>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <rdc:SoortErkenningKeuringsinstantie>AL</rdc:SoortErkenningKeuringsinstantie>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <rdc:SoortMeldingKeuringsinstantie>PC</rdc:SoortMeldingKeuringsinstantie>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <rdc:KINummerMelding>RD17C21</rdc:KINummerMelding>
         <rdc:RDCNummer>307903</rdc:RDCNummer>
         <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 2 items at this level-->
         <!--Optional:-->
         <rdc:Tellerstand Eenheid="Kilometer">150000</rdc:Tellerstand>
         <!--Optional:-->

         <rdc:VoertuigGebreken>
            <!--1 to 20 repetitions:-->
            <rdc:VoertuigGebrek>
               <rdc:GebrekIdentificatie>B07</rdc:GebrekIdentificatie>
               <rdc:GebrekActie>AFK</rdc:GebrekActie>
               <rdc:GebrekAantal>1</rdc:GebrekAantal>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <rdc:GebrekToelichting>?</rdc:GebrekToelichting>
            </rdc:VoertuigGebrek>
             <rdc:VoertuigGebrek>
               <rdc:GebrekIdentificatie>B08</rdc:GebrekIdentificatie>
               <rdc:GebrekActie>AFK</rdc:GebrekActie>
               <rdc:GebrekAantal>1</rdc:GebrekAantal>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <rdc:GebrekToelichting>?</rdc:GebrekToelichting>
            </rdc:VoertuigGebrek>

         </rdc:VoertuigGebreken>
         <rdc:PasnummerKeurmeester>410032</rdc:PasnummerKeurmeester>
         <rdc:PincodeKeurmeester>test23</rdc:PincodeKeurmeester>
         <!--Optional:-->

        </rdc:opvoerenMeldingAfkeuringAPK>
        </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: A little bit of context... and actually asking for help would be nice...

Comment: Sorry of course i'am asking for help, is my first question here.

Comment: The problem is if you see the xml code, i'am try to provide the dim apkvrg.voertuiggebreken with the same information as the xml example.